# 3 sets of button activations - UnityScript for Unity

Tags: menu, unity-game-engine, toggle, unityscript

I'm trying to make a button activate another button, which then once the second button is clicked it will activate the third set of buttons. *Thanks for your help in advance.*

**Here's the current coding in UnityScript:**

```
var toggle : boolean;

function OnGUI()
{
    toggle = GUI.Toggle(Rect(335, 80, 50, 50), toggle, "Button1", "button");

    if (toggle && GUI.Button(Rect(335, 140, 50, 50), "Button2"))
    {
        // This is the part where I want the second button to activate and show the third set of button(s).
        if (toggle && GUI.Button(Rect(335, 140, 50, 50), "Button3"))
        {
        // Third Button content here.
        } 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to implement the logic of "click one button to activate the next" separatly from the unity UI. Just keep booleans of which are active and which are not(or set an int variable if its just one at each point in time) like:

```
bool b1Active = true;
bool b2Active = false;
bool b3Active = false;

if(b1Active && GUI.Button())
{
    b1Active = false;
    b2Active = true;

    // do stuff here      
}

if(b2Active && GUI.Button())
{
    b2Active = false;
    b3Active = true;

    // do other stuff here
}

...
```

I am not sure if this is the most effective way to implement this but i think an approach in this direction could succeed (if i didnt misunderstand your question)

ps: if you dont want to show the buttons if they are not active you might try this instead:

```
if( b1Active)
{
    if(GUI.Button())
    {
        b1Active = false;
        b2Active = true;

        // do stuff here
    }
}
```